# Angular 2 Material Tabs break ViewChild. Ideas for a workaround?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

`Angular 2 rc 5`, `ng-Material 2 alpha 7` coded with `Typescript 1.9`

To get a handle to an element in my template, I use `@ViewChild()`.  Unfortunately, when the element is within an Angular Material tab, ViewChild doesn't work.

**Template**

```
<!-- MdTab blocks access to ViewChild -->
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>Tab Label</template>
        <template md-tab-content>
            <md-card>
                <div #myDiv>I cannot get a reference to this div</div>
            </md-card>            
        </template>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
<!-- No MdTab, so ViewChild will work -->
<section>
    <div #myDiv2>I get a reference to this div</div>
</section>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv;
@ViewChild('myDiv2') myDiv2;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log('myDiv: ',this.myDiv);
    console.log('myDiv2: ',this.myDiv2);
}
```

**Console log**

> myDiv: undefined
>
> myDiv2: Object {nativeElement: div}

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OM7xsIvVYMkX6OwrXQZ4?p=preview

I reported this several months ago but in the meantime it's breaking my application.  Any ideas on how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a functional workaround:

I created an attribute directive with an `(instance)` event that will emit the element hosting that directive.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[myElem]' })
export class ElementRefDirective implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    
    @Output() instance = new EventEmitter<ElementRef>();
    
    /**emit a reference to the host element*/
    ngOnInit(){this.instance.emit(this.el);}
}
```

Now to get a reference to the element in the parent component, I change the template I had in the OP:

```
<div #myDiv>...</div>
```

Instead, I use my new directive, catching the instance of the host element when it is emitted and assigning it to a class property:

```
<div myElem (instance)="myDiv=$event">...</div>
```

Once the `(instance)` event fires within the directive, the `myDiv` property will hold an instance of the div's ElementRef. Now the console output if I log `myDiv` and `myDiv2`:

> myDiv:  Object { nativeElement: div }
>
> myDiv2: Object { nativeElement: div }

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RBlxCSgnPtkD4Nv2JLnw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the details of your project, but do you have to use a template? I removed the template tags around the md-card and could see the reference to div1 in the console in your Plunkr.

Comment: I suspect that removing the template this break something else because `Angular Material tabs` rely on it (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/tabs). Could you link to an updated plunker to show exactly what you did please?